# How close was Maxwell to general relativity?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, history

In a recent paper by Accolierastro's recent video, she goes back to Maxwells seminal paper on electromagnetism, and the section on gravity. In Maxwells paper, he notes the similarity between the lines of force between two poles on a magnet of the same sign, and two masses. By a thought experiment, he considers the energy in the gravitational field by first equating the force from the magnetic and gravitational field lines, and then integrating up to their energies up to a constant. He finally notes that the positive definite nature of energy means gravity must hold some minimum energy per unit volume.

What is he actually talking about here? I don't get how a thought experiment about equating two magnets that also feel gravity can give such a general expression for the energy of a gravitational field. Does modern GR rely on such an energy density? (Like dark energy is an energy per unit volume of space but he's not onto that yet)

Looking for a bit of a history of physics perspective. In the youtube video Acollierastro seems to think Maxwell would've made it to GR if he had another 30 years to live.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Collier is better than a lot of people on YouTube, but her expertise is entirely in galactic astrophysics. When she talks about things far away from that, the general gist is correct (so, better than people like Michio Kaku, where even the gist isn't right) but a lot of the technical details are off.

Comment: The stuff you quote only shows that Maxwell wanted to have a field theory of gravity, which is natural since he'd figured out the field theory of electromagnetism. But GR is built on special relativity, which wasn't around in Maxwell's time. It requires tensor calculus for its formulation, which hadn't been developed yet. And it isn't the _only_ possible relativistic field theory of gravity -- choosing GR over a scalar theory of gravity requires experimental data that Maxwell didn't have. So he was pretty far away for a lot of reasons.

Comment: This is the kind of stuff that is easier if you know more of the surrounding context. What Maxwell is talking about is much less confusing if he had chosen to talk about electric phenomena rather than magnetic phenomena. It is a standard textbook computation these days that the potential energy of attraction between two oppositely charged particles $U=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{qQ}r=\iiint\frac12\epsilon_0\vec E^2\,\mathrm d^3\vec r$ if you first removed the infinite contribution from each point charge and only considered the interaction parts. Maxwell is saying directly analogous to gravity.

Answer (score 9):

This question might perhaps better be asked in the history of science stack exchange. As far as the physics goes, it doesn't seem that Maxwell was particularly close to general relativity; certainly nothing in the quoted extract seems to match GR. The mathematical tools needed to develop general relativity (tensor calculus) were only developed after Maxwell's death. So it seems pretty unlikely that Maxwell could have developed GR.

More possible, indeed perhaps likely, is that Maxwell *could* have discovered special relativity; that just requires basic algebra, and was certainly well within his grasp. The fact that he didn't also tends to suggest that he wouldn't have developed GR, since practically speaking SR is a prerequisite to GR.